# Can a MMU be emulated entirely in software?

Tags: operating-systems, virtual-memory

I'm curious about the viability of creating memory isolated processes on a processor without an MMU.

While it would be inefficient I'm wondering if it's possible to basically create a virtual machine with an MMU and process each instruction on the emulator. In essence the VM would keep track of the current processes memory offset, pre compute memory access to verify the instructions stay in bounds, etc.

Are there alternative approaches? I understand Microsoft did something involving compile timer verification but I couldn't find much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen research papers studying approaches to this, for use on low-end embedded microprocessors.  One approach I have seen is to use SFI (Software Fault Isolation) (or other techniques, like dynamic instrumentation) to provide memory isolation and also patch the code so that, on each backward branch, you check whether the process has run long enough that you should do a context switch.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how this would work wrt to providing memory isolation? If you don't have a badly behaved process you can write position independent code in your compiler but you still need to deal with it potentially harming other processes.

Comment: @FourierFlux, SFI (Software Fault Isolation) provides memory isolation - that's what it does.  It sandboxes memory accesses.  See, e.g., https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs513/2000SP/L13.html, https://people.csail.mit.edu/smcc/projects/pittsfield/pubs/usenix-sec-2006/pittsfield-usenix2006.pdf.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder how repositioning code is handled since more instructions are added. Particularly when using relative addressing.

Comment: This is pretty cool, I wonder if you could make a compiler which only jumped and read/wrote memory relative to hardcoded addresses? Depends on the instruction set I suppose but conceptually it is possible. Wonder why this wasn't researched more.